# stick scrollable div to bottom of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I've got a cordova app using jquery, jquery-mobile, iscroll and iscrollview

I'm not exactly committed to any of these tools.

I've got the jquery-mobile header/footer stuck to the top and bottom of the screen just fine.

I have a scrollable div between the header and footer.  It will contain variable amounts of data.  Sometimes the data will be less than the height of the div and sometimes it will be greater (hence the scrolling)

Here's the tricky part.  I want to stick the bottom of the scrollable div to the top of the footer.  When I add stuff to the div i want the most recently added closest to the top of the footer so the top of the scrollable div looks like its growing upwards towards the bottom of the header as data is added.

Once the top of the scrollable div is fille by its content then i want to be able to scroll it.

Has anyone been able to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat little trick for you.

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Now the CSS

```
div {
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 50px;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100px;
}

/* the magic */
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px; /* matches height of header */
    bottom: 100px; /* matches height of footer */
    left: 0px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

The neat thing about forcing .content to have both a top and a bottom is that it stretches the div so that it's always the proper height.  IF you specified height on it, it wouldn't work, but because the height is determined by the top/bottom property, it's dynamic.  I think this gets you to where you want to be.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20u3xqwb/1/)

Edit: [Here's what it looks like with content](http://jsfiddle.net/20u3xqwb/2/)

---

Edit 2 - forcing content to grow from the bottom.

I'm not sure this is a good idea, and I'm not sure I would ever seriously recommend doing things this way.  However, using vertical-align it's possible to force content to grow from the bottom.  I suspect that it would be better to just set a margin with javascript that shrunk as content grew, but... maybe not.  With all that said, here's *one* way to do things with CSS.

This requires a little bit of restructuring of the content div.

```
<div class="content">
    <span class="margin"></span>
    <span class="inner"></span>
</div>
```

And a little bit more CSS

```
span.left-margin {
    height: 98%;
    width: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}

span.inner {
    width: 99%;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[It looks like this with a little content](http://jsfiddle.net/20u3xqwb/8/)

[It looks like this with a lot of content](http://jsfiddle.net/20u3xqwb/9/)

If you want the scroll bar to stick to the bottom as content comes in, you'll need to do some javascript (easy to google it).

I'm not completely happy with doing things this way because if you set height 100% or width 100%, the content div gets a scrollbar automatically from the beginning.  However... it looks pretty good and should work in most (if not all) browsers.

Comment: this is almost perfect.  the scrolling works fine.  but this attaches the content div to the top of the screen.  i need the content div attached to the bottom of the screen so as data is added it grows up toward the top.

Comment: @user1126515 I updated my answer with growing content from bottom.  Its a bit of a hack, but should work OK.

Comment: sorry for the long delay. i just got back to this today and its not growing the content up for me on android using cordova.